# What's the command to have two or more enchantments on the same item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

On the official Minecraft Wiki page, it says this about mutually exclusive enchantments for swords:

> Sharpness, Smite, and Bane of Arthropods are mutually exclusive. If commands are used to have two or more of these enchantments on the same item, the effects will stack.

When I use command:

```
/enchant <player name> <enchantment ID> <level ID>
```

I get this message:

```
Smite V can't be combined with Sharpness V
```

**What are those *commands* so two or more mutually exclusive enchantments can be put on the same item?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/enchant` restricts enchantments based on survival attainability. You can use the `/give` command to provide the player with an item that already contains a list of enchantments. For example, the following provides the player with a Sharpness 5 and Smite 5 sword:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:16s,lvl:5s},{id:17s,lvl:5s}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

our used command is

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {Unbreakable:100,ench:[{id:18,lvl:32762},{id:20,lvl:32762},{id:16,lvl:32762},{id:34,lvl:32762}]}
```